Assigning a Static IP Address in Bookworm
I've just done a clean install of Bookworm Lite on a Pi 4+, and now I want to assign it a static IP address. I can't use DHCP, as I intend this box to be my DHCP server. All the other instructions I can find say to edit /etc/dhcpcd.conf, which doesn't exist on Bookworm, and which, when I tried it, didn't work anyway.
Can anyone please tell me how to manually set my static IP address? Thanks.
EDIT: The problem with using NetworkManager is that I had accidentally deleted all my network connections. nmgui admittedly does allow the creation of new connection profiles, however my minimal OS install does not include nmgui. nmcli can also add connections, but I had no idea what values to plug in.

use e.g. nmtui to change the settings

"All the other instructions I can find say to edit /etc/dhcpcd.conf". FYI, dhcpcd has been cast aside in favor of NetworkManager (nmcli if you're running Lite). I think you're looking for dhcpd for the DHCP server role.

However: @Dirk's comment may be worth looking into... In my case (I run Lite/headless systems), so I'd use nmcli. There are literally hundreds of "How-Tos" explaining how to set a static IP using nmcli (for instance). Suggest you try one of those.

@Seamus nmtui is the 'text user interface' and is also available / usable on lite systems (see answer below)

@Dirk: Ah yes - an ncurses "semi-GUI"  :)

Does this answer your question? How do I set up networking on Raspberry Pi OS - Bookworm and look at Network Manager hotspot.

I was eventually able to bootstrap a connection by editing /etc/network/interfaces as follows:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

After that, I was able to fine-tune the connection using nmcli, and to allow DHCP to configure the interface.

This is what I did to set a static IP on Bookworm:

at the command line do: sudo nmtui
edit the connection you want (eg WiFi)
change ipv4 config to manual

Press Enter on 'Manual'
Then use the mouse to scroll down (don’t be fooled by the nearly full vertical scroll bar), and set these:

Then scroll down so that you can see how to OK the changes. Hope this works for you.

What is the point of obscuring parts of private network addresses.

@Milliways. I totally agree. It was completely pointless, and I knew it at the time. But I really can't help being paranoid :)
